# javascript Excel.application closes excel prematurely

Tags: javascript, excel

I have made a small javascript, that can take  data from a html table and send it to excel. The function is triggered using an onclick button.

```
<input type='button' value='Export to EXCEL' onclick='write_to_excel();return;'>
```

great so far.  the data arrives in excel and everything is fine.

But the html page contains a lot of mouse overeffects and other javascript functions. and as soon one of the these are triggered  excel shutsdown...

How can i keep excel open  and keep the data ,  when the webpage behind is still running scripts?

here is the code:

```
    function write_to_excel() 
{

str="";

var test=testForActiveX();
 var mytable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var rowCount = mytable.rows.length;
var colCount = mytable.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].getElementsByTagName("td").length; 

var ExcelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var ExcelSheet = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Sheet");


ExcelSheet.Application.Visible = true;



//  første table læses for at finde overskrifter 
    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) 
    {   
        for(var j=0; j<colCount; j++) 
        {           
            str= mytable.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j].innerText ;

            ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(i+1,j+1).Value = str;
        }
    }

// anden tabel læses for at finde data 
var mytable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[1];
var rowCount = mytable.rows.length;
var colCount = mytable.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].getElementsByTagName("td").length; 


    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) 
    {   
        for(var j=0; j<colCount; j++) 
        {           
            str= '=\"'+ mytable.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j].innerText +'\"';


            //if (mytable.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j].innerText 


            //str='=value("'+mytable.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j].innerText +'")';
            //det lang space er for at undgå excel konvertering 
            ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(i+1+1,j+1).Value = str;
        }
    }



ExcelSheet=null;
ExcelApp=null;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function write_to_excel() 
{
    var ExcelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    var ExcelSheet = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Sheet");

    ExcelSheet.Application.Visible = true;

    ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Value = "test";

    ExcelSheet=null;
    ExcelApp=null;
}
```

This is a very cut-down version of your code. When I click the button, I see Excel pop up and then immediately close itself (I don't have to do anything else with the page, it just closes straight away).

The reason is that you've *told it to*, albeit only implicitly. Your last two lines are the problem. Both the worksheet and excel itself are only open because you have variables holding them, ExcelSheet and ExcelApp. At the end, though, you set them both to null - so Excel closes because neither the sheet nor the app-instance exist!

The only question I can't answer is why it doesn't happen immediately for you, but instead they stay open until you trigger some other javascript. I can't reproduce that - whatever else I try to do, I always see the Excel window close as soon as both variables are set to null.

The solution, then, is to declare those variables at a global scope (i.e. not in the function where they'll just go out of scope as soon as the function ends), and not to set those two variables to null UNTIL you want Excel to close. Alternatively, don't bother at all anyway, and just leave it up to the user to close Excel manually.

```
var ExcelApp;
var ExcelSheet;

function write_to_excel() 
{
    ExcelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    ExcelSheet = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Sheet");

    ExcelSheet.Application.Visible = true;

    ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Value = "test";
}
```